# Want to test kernel 4.4 - How to backup whole system?

Tags: backup

Sup,

Im running 15.10 and my touchpad isnt working; I was advised to test kernel 4.4 to fix it.
In case something fails (which happened under 14.04.3), I want to recover the whole system as it is now.

thx

Comment: Why would you backup your entire system just to test a new kernel? Keep older ones, test 4.4 and then if something is not right just fallback and remove the new version. Backing up the system is too much effort for too few.

Comment: This [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/714093/119531) gives a detailed instruction as to how-to backup your whole system.

Answer (score 2):

This is a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  You don't actually need to back up the whole system, as if you're not happy with the new kernel you can [always boot your machine to the older one via GRUB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82140/how-can-i-boot-with-an-older-kernel-version). You won't even need to uninstall the new kernel!

But if you really want to backup your system there are programs like DéjàDup to do so. You can find it in Ubuntu through the Dash, searching for "backup".

Comment: Not exactly an answer. I already told the OP about it in the comments.

Comment: Your comment was correct. Read the exacts words of the question, not just the title: the OP doesn't really want to back up his whole system, he just wants to be sure to be able to recover his old system if he's unhappy with the new kernel. Therefore "how to back up my whole system" is the XY Problem, and this answer is perfectly appropriate as it solves the *real* OP's problem.

Comment: Must disagree. You can suggest the OP to do so, but this does not answer his question: how to backup the whole system.

Comment: On SE this is considered a valid answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263661/does-stack-exchange-allow-for-answers-which-question-the-validity-or-stance-of-t

Comment: Didn't say it wasn't valid, but it does not answer the original question.

Comment: Ok, thx, but does anyone know how to get my touchpad working?

Comment: Well, actually *this* is the original problem. Installing the kernel and backing up the system aren't the real questions. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried installing kernel 4.4 on 14.04.3, which finishes, but gave me errors (I dont know what kind of errors, though) and on 15.10, which didnt fix it either.

Comment: You should open a new question for that. And I think that you should probably open another one concerning your original problem -- touchpad not working.